# referencing the precompiled header from a subfolder causes build to fail

Tags: c++, visual-c++, precompiled-headers

I have a project in which I use a precompiled header. I have referenced it from a cpp file in subfolder. The include looks like this:

```
#include "../pch.h"
```

When I try to Compile, I get this error:

```
Error   C1010   unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "pch.h"' to your source? [path to file]\ECS.cpp    9
```

If I move the cpp file to the **same directory** as the precompiled header, I can compile normally. I do need to change the reference in the header file first.

Is there another way to get rid of this annoyance other than removing the Precompiled Header from the project?

Comment: I highly recommend not using precompiled headers unless your build is incredibly huge and takes a very long time.  Issues like this are not worthwhile for small programs.  You should profile the build times, with and without precompiled headers.

Comment: right, that's probably what I'll do. But it shouldn't be such an issue to use it, should it? I really want to know what I'm doing wrong and how can do it right.

Comment: There are a lot of unwritten rules about precompiled headers and Visual Studio.  You may have found one.